# comparing two table columns in mysql results in duplicate

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, I've been trying to print the result from each but they are being duplicated. These are the two MySQL tables and the result. Notice the duplication.

[image]

The sql code for the project is:

```
SELECT * FROM savings,savtype WHERE cust_id=".$_SESSION['user']
```

I'm also looking for a work around this, in the meantime, id appreciate any assistance on this.

Comment: does savings and savtype contains only two columns otherwise pls keep full schema of tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you are not specifying *how* the two tables are related. You need to add that, either via an explicit ... JOIN ... (USING|ON)

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  savings JOIN savtype USING (savtype_id) 
WHERE 
  cust_id = ".$_SESSION['user']
```

or by providing the criteria in the where clause.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  savings, savtype
WHERE 
  savings.savtype_id = savtype.savtype_id AND
  cust_id = ".$_SESSION['user']
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, i really appreciate offering some help on this @MartinSchneider

Answer (score 0):

As I understand from the screenshot you added, it makes joint between those tables, and what you probably want it left join from **savings** and **savtype** tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM `savings`
LEFT JOIN `savtype`
ON savings.savtype_id=savtype.savtype_id
where cust_id=".$_SESSION['user'] .";
```

Update if this did the trick,
You can learn more about left join here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: This also worked @PiniCheyni, I'm going to study up some more on on w3schools before i continue with the code. Thank you loads